# How do I fix this body rig

Tags: rigging, blender-internal-render-engine

Im using rainv2 using this link https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da

im following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C2ClFO3FAY&t=784s

This is the problem im experiencing im fairly new to blender but know the basics to please help,

https://youtu.be/sb7xfeVRsfA

I dont know why the rig wont behave like normal it like the objects aren't parented to each other or something, I would really appreciate the help as I really want to do this tutorial, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need enter to pose mode to do that

- select the armeture and pres ctrl+tab
- or you can select and change object mode to pose mode when armeture selected
  [image]